# Is not -rf command in Maven reliable?

Tags: maven, maven-3

I was building a multi-module project with Maven3. In a module, it gave a "build failure" and said after completing my error, I can use -rf :moduleName in order to continue my build. I did not change anything and gave the same command this time with -rf :moduleName as the maven said and built successfully. What may be the possible reasons of this situation and is not -rf command in Maven reliable?

Comment: Then the error you had happens randomly ;) Maybe you could post the stacktrace and your POM?

Comment: That happened two days ago and unfortunately, I dont have those files anymore. The build lasted 40 Minutes and then gave this error. That abused my trust to Maven a little bit:)

Comment: You should check the log files and identify the root cause of this...cause that sounds not like a Maven problem...And of course pom file and error output would be helpful..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either you have a non-deterministic test which fails randomly, you need to look for why and fix it.

Etiher it is just a plugin maven error, for exemple maven-clean-plugin may fail under some OS if target directory is used (explorer, etc.) and may work when it is reexecuted a second time if the lock was released.

Either you have snapshots dependencies and parallel builds and share maven artifact repository with others teamates, like Nexus or Artifactory.

For example, if module A depends on B, in your local build the build chain will be "B, then A". If A doesn't compile, B is built and put into local repository, but the complete build chain fails when building project A.

Then if you use -rf flag, the build chain doesn't recompile B and starts building from module A.

But imagine that you have a continuous deployment, like Teamcity or Jenkins, the project B may be rebuilt with same version number (snapshot) and put in shared central repository. In this case, module A retrieve last available snapshot for module B which can not be the right artifact (if you have local modification), and A may have no error when compiling with this code for module B.

You can avoid this problem either by rebuilding the chain entirely, either by using the -o flag which means "offline" mode (ie maven will retrieve artifacts only from local repository).

To fix correctly it, you should take care of the error and investigate what the specific error means. It was a compile error ? a test failure ? a maven plugin error ? Start by reading the error message, it may help :)

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer. Is it always more secure to add -o flag into maven parameters?

Comment: You need to avoid -o when a maven plugin or a new added dependency is not available in local repository because you have maven download it from central repository, but when you start a build the first time, this missing dependency will be cached into local repository. After that, you can use -o, until you add a new dependency in pom